# Dynamic Stored Procedure to retrieve data from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table named `CM`:

```
client_no     ac_no     ac_group
--------------------------------
 MGO           025        033
 CGO           035        036
 MGO           015        038
 MGO           045        039
 cGO           085        031
```

I want to create a dynamic stored procedure to fetch the data from `CM`.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetInfo
      @client_no Nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(2000)
      SET @SQL = 'SELECT client_no, acc_no, ac_group FROM CM WHERE client_no = ''' + @client_no + ''''
      EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Comment: mention your expected output

Comment: in your question u said that u want dynamic stored procedure to fetch the data from CM,according to your question this query is correct.

Comment: wait i will modified soon

Comment: sure...waiting for ur answer